# Auto-property overridden with expression body

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-6.0

When using abstract getter-only auto-properties that are then overridden with an expression body property, does the Roslyn compiler still create an use the backing field?

From my understanding, the compiler will create a backing field for an auto-property, but it will not create a backing field for an expression body property.

**Base abstract class**

```
public abstract class FooPage
{
     protected abstract string PageName { get; }
}
```

**Derived class**

```
public class BarPage : FooPage
{
     protected override string PageName => "FooBar";
}
```

I am wondering what happens in this scenario. I found this in Roslyn's wiki..
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodies-on-property-like-function-members

but still not sure what actually happens under the covers.

Comment: If you are very interested in such matters, the quickest way to resolve it is to actually compile code, and then use a tool like `ildasm` or `ILSpy` (in IL mode) to look at the generated code. Obviously the result of this cannot be generalized to make definite statements about what the compiler *should* do or *must* do (that can only be answered by standards), but for "I wonder how" questions it often suffices.

Comment: `FooPage` does not declare an auto-property -- it declares an abstract property. The syntax is the same, but the semantics are different. If you make your property `virtual` instead, *then* you've got an auto-property (complete with backing field). And when you know that, and that expression body properties don't use a backing field, and how `FooPage` and `BarPage` are compiled individually, you should be able to reason out for yourself how the compiler must (almost necessarily) implement this.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @svick: because I am a lazy, indolent wretch who often needs some explicit encouragement to post answers rather than off-the-cuff comments... but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a general note: if you are very interested in such matters, the quickest way to resolve it is to actually compile code, and then use a tool like ildasm or ILSpy (in IL mode) to look at the generated code. Obviously the result of this cannot be generalized to make definite statements about what the compiler should do or must do (that can only be answered by standards), but for "I wonder how" questions it often suffices.

Expression body properties are simply shorthand for writing out methods; they will never cause a backing field to be generated. `BarPage` could be written out in full like this:

```
public class BarPage : FooPage
{
     protected override string PageName 
     {
         get { return "FooBar"; }
     }
}
```

This is irrespective of how the property is implemented in `FooPage`, and whether it has a backing field there or not. In your example, it does not, because this isn't an auto-property:

```
protected abstract string PageName { get; }
```

This is an abstract property, which existed before read-only auto-properties were introduced. It looks very much like an auto-property, but it isn't one. The following isn't legal C# syntax but reflects the IL translation better:

```
protected string PageName 
{
    abstract get;
}
```

No backing field here. On the other hand, the following *is* a read-only auto-property and *does* have a backing field:

```
protected virtual string PageName { get; }
```

Imagine it looking like this (again, not legal C# syntax):

```
private readonly $PageNameBackingField;
protected string PageName 
{
    virtual get { return $PageNameBackingField; }
}
```

But, crucially, this still has no influence at all on the implementation in `BarPage`, because the getter there doesn't rely on the base implementation. If you referenced `base.PageName` explicitly, you would find that this works if the base property is `virtual`, and will give an error if the base property is `abstract`. You'd still not be accessing the backing field directly (which is good; insulating clients from the details about how the property is implemented is the whole point of properties).